# How to make one object use functions from 2 different classes?

Tags: javascript, class

I'm currently learning to work with classes using chess game as a project. And I'm stuck with Queen and King. "ReturnMovesList()" function is supposed to set "piece".moves array, depending on an object. I already wrote a script for each piece. The script itself shouldn't be important, but I included it in a case.

```
class Piece {
    constructor() {
        //not important
    }

    GetLegalMoves() {
        this.SetMoves();
        //something else
    }
}

class Rook extends Piece{
    SetMoves() {
        let legal,
            rm = [[1, 0], [-1, 0], [0, 1], [0, -1]];

        for (let i in rm) {
            let tmp = [];
            for (var step = 0; step < this.step; step++){
                legal = isLegal(pposChar, pposNum, rm[i][0], rm[i][1]);
                if (legal) {
                    tmp.push(legal);
                    pposChar += rm[i][0];
                    pposNum += rm[i][1];
                    if (isKingAttacked(legal))
                        tmp.map(n => sqsToBlock.push(n));
                } else
                    break;
            }
            tmp.map(n => this.moves.push(n));
        }
    }
}

class Bishop extends Piece {
    SetMoves() {
        let tmp = [], legal;
        for (var i = -1; i <= 1; i += 2) {
            for (var j = -1; j <= 1; j += 2) {
                tmp = [];
                let checkChar = pposChar, checkNum = pposNum;
                for (var step = 0; step < this.step; step++) {
                    legal = isLegal(checkChar, checkNum, i, j);
                    if (legal) {
                        tmp.push(legal);
                        checkChar += i;
                        checkNum += j;
                        if (isKingAttacked(legal))
                            for (var k = 0; k < tmp.length; k++)
                                sqsToBlock.push(tmp[k]);
                    } else
                        break;
                }
                for (let k = 0; k < tmp.length; k++) {
                    this.moves.push(tmp[k]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class Queen extends ??? {
    //need both functions
}
```

How to make Queen object use both functions? Maybe I'm doing something fundamentally wrong?

Comment: Declare the functions outside the `class` declarations as simple stand-alone functions, and then you can refer to them by name in any `class` declaration you want.

Comment: Not related, but this design looks dirty: your classes reference state that is not defined by the class instance. For instance, there are calls to `isKingAttacked`, `isLegal`, ... which clearly depend on the state of the board, but are not really known in the class instance.

Comment: This is where people usually say to you "inheritance bad"

Comment: trincot, class method should only include class instances? These function initially were inside of a class, but I separated it, cause didn't see the reason for them to be there.

Comment: Your class instance should have all it needs to function. It is bad design to use state that is not incorporated in the class. There are several ways to solve this, one of them is to have a property in your piece class that references the board it is on. Then you can access `this.board.isLegal`, ...etc. But even better would be to create the move list outside of the piece class, because that list depends on more than just that particular piece...

Answer (score 2):

You could apply the setMoves function from both other classes:

```
class Queen extends Piece {
  setMoves() {
     Bishop.prototype.setMoves.call(this);
     Rook.prototype.setMoves.call(this);
   }
 }
```

Multi inheritance itself (that one class extends two other classes) is not possible. Another approach would be to implement the different moves in different methods of Piece, or as standalone functions, then call the ones you need from the `setMoves` implementations.

Here's how I'd implement the whole thing:

```
 class Board {
   pieces = [];
   isValid(x, y) { /*...*/ }
   addPiece(piece) {
      piece.board = this;
      this.pieces.push(piece);
   }
 }

 class Piece {
   static moves = [];

   validMoves() {
     return this.constructor.moves.filter(([x, y]) => this.board.isValid(x, y));
    }
 }

 class Bishop extends Piece {
   static moves = [/*...*/];

   // no reimplementation of validMoves necessary
  }

 class Queen extends Piece {
   static moves = [...Bishop.moves, /*...*/];
 }
```